# searching for pages explaining codes

Tags: google-search

Google does not allow searching for !

!-f becomes -f

What search engines find pages with !-f?

Comment: For the record, in Perl, -f is used to check to see if a file exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other characters too that do not return any result (eg @, #, $ etc.). Infact the only two characters that are honoured are '&' and '_'
Check this [post](http://www.marketingshift.com/2006/3/google-special-character-search-string.cfm).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It seems to work if you put it in quotes, like "!-f", did you try that?</strike>
from http://knol.google.com/k/barry-welford/the-humble-exclamation-mark/3fhotx4fqh463/2# :

> Google doesn’t recognize special characters such as exclamation points, question marks, or the @ sign. These types of characters are so common that including them in a search would greatly slow the delivery of the search results.

Comment: It doesn't look like its possible, see here http://knol.google.com/k/barry-welford/the-humble-exclamation-mark/3fhotx4fqh463/2#